# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to write a generator for training Tensor Flow, and understand how they work.

This works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as ks
inp = ks.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
mid = ks.layers.Dense(10)(inp)
out = ks.layers.Dense(1)(mid)
model = ks.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile()
```

I have tried two ways of defining a generator:

```py
def my_generator():
    while True:
        yield np.random.uniform(), 1
```

```py
class my_generator:
    def next():
        return np.random.uniform(), 1
```

and they both fail with a similar error on this line:

```py
model.fit(my_generator, steps_per_epoch=10)
```

with errors

```py
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'function'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

```py
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'type'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

respectively.

I have already read through [the python wiki on generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and think my generators are both correct. Why, then, is Tensor Flow complaining?

---

**Note**:
Neither wrapping each tuple element in an `np.array`, nor the tuple itself, has proven successful.

Comment: I'm still lost...

Comment: How do I specify the type, s.t. this will be resolved?